# Is stochastic modelling a subset of Frequentist and Bayesian points of view?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

From what I know of stochastic modelling it seems to me that this technique takes a Frequentist approach.

For example, and please correct me if I am wrong, but isn't a Monte Carlo Simulation a Frequentist approach?

If possible, I would appreciate any learning resources around this topic.

Comment: @ icu : Hi Monte Carlo is "Law of Large Number" approach, nothing more, nothing less. LLN is used in both in frequentist and Bayesian techniques. Best regards.